# How to avoid wrong locations in android while getting locations through FusedLocation?

Tags: android, location, android-location, fusedlocationproviderapi, android-fusedlocation

I am getting device' locations through fused location service, then sending these location to backend to draw line on map. It is working fine.
As we know, fused location is a free service and it has low accuracy (as compared to google paid services), when user stops on a location for a while (e.g: for 30 minutes), It will draw random lines. As shown in image:

[image]

I am calculating distance from these location, now when I am calculating distance in this scenario, it will also calculate distance of this cluster/random lines.
How can I avoid this extra distance?

Comment: Use gps. Its free. All the rest is inaccurate.

Comment: What you describe is normal behaviour of a gps receiver on no movement.

Comment: I have no idea why you would use something inaccurate.

Comment: I have no idea how a paid service could increase accuracy.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I can not use gps, I am using GPS, but in this case, I have to use fused location service, as I have to get location even if the app is in background or killed. With GPS, I can not do this because some devices stop the execution if there is too much processing.

Comment: Furthermore, GPS is also drawing such lines, If user is stopped at a location, it will return location within some specific radius, it will not return the exactly same points.

Comment: Furthermore? What are you telling? Didnt you read my second comment?

Comment: Yes you are right, every free service is returning such locations, because these are not according to roads, buildings etc. My question is that how We can avoid such locations?

Comment: `every free service is returning such locations,` I have no idea what free services would be. And not even i do understand services? Why are you talking abouit services?

Comment: Services mean, location providers, can you please give me any solution to avoid such location ?

Comment: Which location providers do you have in mind?

Comment: I am using Fused location

Comment: Also tried GPS and network locations

Comment: Only gps will show this drifting i think. You can do nothing against it. Even Garmin gps receivers show this behaviour.